# which version of hadoop to be used with nutch 1.15

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I'm planning to build a web crawler using nutch and solr. I want to know which version of hadoop should I install to work with nutch 1.15.

Comment: Unless you need really a cluster to distribute your work-load: Nutch is able to run without an extra Hadoop installation in so-called "local mode".

Answer (score 0):

Nutch 1.15 is built with Hadoop 2.2.0 but it runs also on Hadoop installations using higher versions of Hadoop 2.x and 3.x.